# Parse Server (post migration) Static Images

Tags: android, ios, mongodb, heroku, parse-platform

I migrated my parse application and everything works great. However, I have read things saying that my static images need to use S3 because they are currently being accessed from the original Parse.com still but then I have also read that there is nothing that needs to be done they are simply stored in MongoDB (I am using mLab).

This needs to be cleared up somewhere. I am using mLab and Heroku and only have about 10 static image files. I even ran parse-files-utils (https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-files-utils) to make sure but that didn't seem to change anything.

Right now everything is working fine but how can I confirm that the images will still be able to be accessed after Parse shuts down. Thank you!

(Also the parse-files-utils says images exist in parse/files under Heroku but am not sure how to access that folder exactly)